# Wacom touch screen not working at all Ubuntu 16 or 17 on Thinkpad x230 Tablet

Tags: tablet, touchscreen, wacom

I purchased a refurbished Thinkpad x230 Tablet laptop and installed first Ubuntu 16 and now upgraded to 17. The Wacom touch screen is not working with stylus or finger. I have tried to xinput --enable the device, but it made no difference.

Here are the properties for the pen stylus, for example. Can you see any problems or recommend anything else to try? Thanks.

```
Device 'Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus':
Device Enabled (140):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (271): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (272):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (273):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (274):    10.000000
Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event5"
Wacom Tablet Area (300):    0, 0, 27760, 15694
Wacom Rotation (301):   0
Wacom Pressurecurve (302):  0, 0, 100, 100
Wacom Serial IDs (303): 230, 0, 2, 0, 0
Wacom Serial ID binding (304):  0
Wacom Pressure Threshold (305): 27
Wacom Sample and Suppress (306):    2, 4
Wacom Enable Touch (307):   1
Wacom Hover Click (308):    1
Wacom Enable Touch Gesture (309):   0
Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters (310):   0, 0, 250
Wacom Tool Type (311):  "STYLUS" (293)
Wacom Button Actions (312): "Wacom button action 0" (313), "Wacom button action 1" (314), "Wacom button action 2" (315)
Wacom button action 0 (313):    1572865
Wacom button action 1 (314):    1572867
Wacom button action 2 (315):    1572866
Wacom Pressure Recalibration (316): 1
Device Product ID (264):    1386, 230
Wacom Debug Levels (317):   0, 0
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this? Reason I ask is I'm considering getting a used touchscreen laptop like an x230 and would use MATE ubuntu on it probably. But if it's not going to work then I won't bother. If it didn't work did you find alternative hardware that does work with Ubuntu?

Comment: @rusl Unfortunately I was never able to get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and opening the screen. It happened to me after booting with an opened screen. Possibly the wacom hardware thought the laptop was in a closed state. If it's working on Windows but not on Ubuntu though this solution most likely won't work.

Mine is a Thinkpad S1 3rd gen. Also a tablet/laptop hybrid.

Comment: Sorry, no luck! I tried the above, also in combination with suspending the machine and re-logging in, but it did not activate the sound. But thanks for the suggestion. Still no solution found.

Answer (score 0):

According to the UbuntuHandbook.org, there are scripts to make those run correctly.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/enable-screen-rotation-docking-for-thinkpad-x220-x230-in-ubuntu-16-04/

Add this repo, update, then install `thinkpad-scripts`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:martin-ueding/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install thinkpad-scripts
```

To uninstall, simply uninstall `thinkpad-scripts`.

```
sudo apt remove thinkpad-scripts && sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I tried this with Ubuntu 17 and receive a repo error: "The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/martin-ueding/stable/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file."